# Панель с кнопками для редактирования стикеров появляется не при каждом нажатии на каждый стикер

Tags: java, intellij-idea, swing, отладка, listener

Пишу канбан-доску, при нажатии на стикер внизу окна должна появляться панель с кнопкой редактирования, чтения и удаления. При первом нажатии на стикер (если их несколько) всё работает нормально, но если попытаться нажать на другой в той же колонке, то хоть условие, при выполнении которого панель с кнопками должна становиться видимой, выполняется, видимой она не становится, хотя нужно, чтобы при клике на любой стикер панель JToolBar становилась видимой. При перетаскивании стикера в другую колонку, когда стикер становится первым в своей колонке, проблема пропадает, но если перетащит к нему ещё один, то вновь появляется.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Window window = new Window();

    }
}
```

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Window extends JFrame {
    public JButton Edit;
    public JButton Read;//кнопка, выводящая втикер во всё окно с текстом
    public JButton Delete;
    private Window window;
    private JToolBar jtb;

    public boolean stickerToolBarActivated;

    public Window() {
        window= this;
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        Desk d = new Desk(/*window.getWidth())*/);
        createMenu(d);
        add(d);
        setDefaultSizeToProgressTypesColumns(d, this);
        d.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));

        StickerListener sl = new StickerListener(d, this);
        this.addMouseMotionListener(sl);
        this.addMouseListener(sl);

        this.addComponentListener(new ComponentListener() {
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                setDefaultSizeToProgressTypesColumns(d,window);
            }

            @Override
            public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {}
        });

        jtb = new JToolBar();
        Edit = new JButton("Редактровать");
        jtb.add(Edit);
        Delete = new JButton("Удалить");
        jtb.add(Delete);
        Read = new JButton("Просмотреть");
        jtb.add(Read);
        add(jtb, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jtb.setVisible(false);
        stickerToolBarActivated=false;




        setVisible(true);
    }



private void createMenu(Desk d)
{
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu DeskFile = new JMenu("Файл");
    JMenuItem SaveDesk = new JMenuItem("Сохранить доску"/*, /*функция*/);
    DeskFile.add(SaveDesk);
    menuBar.add(DeskFile);

    JMenu StickerOptions = new JMenu("Стикер");
    JMenuItem NewSticker = new JMenuItem("Добавить стикер");
    NewSticker.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            d.ProgressTypes.get(0).addSticker();
            setDefaultSizeToProgressTypesColumns(d, window);
            d.repaint();

        }
    });
    StickerOptions.add(NewSticker);
    menuBar.add(StickerOptions);



    add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
}

    public JToolBar getStickerToolbar() {
        return jtb;
    }

    public static void setDefaultSizeToProgressTypesColumns(Desk d, Window window)
    {
        int x=0;
        int y=0;
        int WindowWidth = window.getWidth();
        int WindowHeight = window.getHeight();
        int ptCount = d.ProgressTypes.size();
        for(ProgressType pt: d.ProgressTypes)
        {
            pt.x=x;
            pt.y=y;
            pt.width= WindowWidth/ptCount;
            pt.height = WindowHeight;
            x+=pt.width;

            for(int s=0; s<pt.stickers.size(); ++s) {
                pt.stickers.get(s).setWidth(pt.width);
                pt.stickers.get(s).setHeight(pt.width);
                pt.stickers.get(s).y=pt.height/20+pt.width*s;
                pt.stickers.get(s).x=pt.x;
            }
        }
    }

    public JButton getEdit() {
        return Edit;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Desk extends JPanel {
    public ArrayList<ProgressType> ProgressTypes;
   // private ArrayList<Sticker> stickers;

    public int  width;

    public Desk(/*int width*/)
    {
        ProgressTypes = new ArrayList<ProgressType>();
        ProgressTypes.add(new ProgressType("Идеи"));//можно птом добаить адаптер по английский
        ProgressTypes.add(new ProgressType("Сделать"));
        ProgressTypes.add(new ProgressType("В процессе"));
        ProgressTypes.add(new ProgressType("Тестируется"));
        ProgressTypes.add(new ProgressType("Готово"));

    }




    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);

       for(ProgressType pt: ProgressTypes) {
           pt.paint(g);
       }
        for(ProgressType pt: ProgressTypes)
        for(Sticker s : pt.stickers)
            s.paint(g);
    }




    /*public int findSticker(String search)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<stickers.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(stickers.get(i).title.matches(search))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
    */

}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProgressType extends JPanel {
    public ArrayList<Sticker> stickers;
    public String name;


    public int x, y, width, height;

    public ProgressType(String n)
    {
        this.name = n;
        stickers = new ArrayList<>();
       /* StickerBuilder sb = new StickerBuilder();
        sb.setTitle("test");
        // sb.setProgress(ProgressTypes.get(0));
        //sb.setText();
        stickers.add(sb.getSticker());
        stickers.get(0).y=height/20;*/
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        final BasicStroke borderLine = new BasicStroke(4.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                                                          BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND, 5.0f);
         g2d.setStroke(borderLine);
         g2d.setColor(Color.black);
         g2d.drawLine(x, y, x+width, y);
         g2d.drawLine(x, y, x, y+height);
         g2d.drawLine(x, y+height/20, x+width, y+height/20); //height/20 это высота шапки таблицы
         g2d.drawLine(x+width, y, x+width, y+height);

        //for (Sticker s : stickers)
            //s.paint(g);
    }


    public int findSticker(String search) {

        for(int i=0; i<stickers.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(stickers.get(i).title.matches(search))
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void addSticker()
    {
        StickerBuilder sb = new StickerBuilder();
        Sticker s = sb.getSticker();
        s.y=(height/20)+(width*stickers.size())+5;
        stickers.add(s);
        repaint();
    }

    public void addSticker(Sticker s)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<stickers.size(); ++i)
        {
            stickers.get(i).y=s.y=(height/20)+(width*(i+1))+5*(i+1);
        }
        s.y=(height/20);
        stickers.add(s);
    }

}
```

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Sticker extends JPanel {
    public String text;
    private String Progress;
    public String title;
    private BufferedImage img;

    public int x;
    public int y;

    public int width;//добавить возможность изменения
    public int height;
    //ДОБАВИТЬ ВОЗМОЖНОСТЬ ЗАДАВАТЬ ЦВЕТ
    public Sticker ( String text, String Progress,String title, int x, int y)
    {
        this.text=text;
        this.Progress=Progress;
        this.title = title;
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.width = -1;
        this.height = -1;

        try {
            /*"C:\\1\\example.jpg"*/
            URL resource = Sticker.class.getResource("\\transparentSticker.png");
            img = null;
            this.img = ImageIO.read(Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile());
            System.out.println("c");
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println("caught");
        }
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void setProgress(String progress) {
        Progress = progress;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width){
        this.width = width;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }


    public Sticker clone()
    {
        Sticker s= new Sticker(text, Progress, title, x, y);
        s.setHeight(width);
        s.setWidth(width);
        return s;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        System.out.print("p");
        g.drawImage(img, x, y, width-4, height,  null);
        String NormStr;
        if(title!=null) {
            NormStr = NormalizeLabel(title, g);
            g.drawString(NormStr, x, y + width / 5);
        }
        if(text!=null) {
            NormStr = NormalizeLabel(text, g);

            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
            int hgt = fm.getHeight();

            String [] n=NormStr.split("\n");
            for(int i= 0; i<n.length; ++i) {
                g.drawString(n[i], x, y + width / 5 + hgt * 13 / 10 * (i + 1));
                if(width / 5 + hgt * 13 / 10 * (i + 1)>=width*0.75)
                {
                    g.drawString("...", x, y + width / 5 + hgt * 13 / 10 * (i + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private String NormalizeLabel(String s, Graphics g)
    {
        String NormalizedString = "";
        String buf="";

        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
        int hgt= fm.getHeight();
        int strw=0;

        for(int i=0; i<s.length(); ++i)
        {
           buf+=s.charAt(i);
           strw=fm.stringWidth(buf);
           if(strw>=width*0.75)
           {
               NormalizedString+=buf;
               NormalizedString+="\n";
               buf="";

           }
        }
        NormalizedString+=buf;
        return NormalizedString;
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface Builder {
    void setText(String text);
    void setProgress(String Progress);
    void setTitle(String title);
    Sticker getSticker();
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StickerBuilder implements Builder{
    public StickerBuilder() {
    }

    private String text;
    private String Progress;
    private String title;

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void setProgress(String progress) {
        Progress = progress;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Sticker getSticker()
    {
        return new Sticker(text, Progress, title, 0, 0);//возможно, стоит добавить функцию для х и у
    }

}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class StickerChanger implements Builder {

    private Sticker sticker;
    public StickerChanger(Sticker sticker) {
        this.sticker = sticker;
    }

    @Override
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.sticker.setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void setProgress(String Progress) {
        this.sticker.setProgress(Progress);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.sticker.setTitle(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Sticker getSticker() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StickerListener implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

    private ArrayList<ProgressType> PTs;
    private boolean StickerIsBeingDragged;
    private int DistanceToTheEndX;
    private int DistanceToTheEndY;
    private Sticker CurrentSticker;
    private Desk d;
    private Window window;
    private boolean sd2;

    private final int Y_DELTA=50;


    private ActionListener del;
    private ActionListener edit;
    private ActionListener rd;

    private StickerEditorWindow sew;

    public StickerListener(Desk d, Window w)
    {
        this.d = d;
        this.PTs=d.ProgressTypes;
        this.DistanceToTheEndX=this.DistanceToTheEndY=0;
        this.StickerIsBeingDragged = this.sd2=false;
        this.window =w;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (StickerIsBeingDragged)
        {
            sd2=true;
            CurrentSticker.x=e.getX()-DistanceToTheEndX;
            CurrentSticker.y=e.getY()-DistanceToTheEndY;
            System.out.println(CurrentSticker.x+" "+CurrentSticker.y+" "+e.getX()+" "+ e.getY()+" "+"dragged");
            d.repaint();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        boolean f = true;

        if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)


                for (ProgressType pt : PTs) {
                    for (Sticker s : pt.stickers) {
                        System.out.println((e.getX() >= s.x) + " " + (e.getX() <= (s.x + s.width))+ " " +
                        (e.getY()-Y_DELTA >= s.y ) + " " + (e.getY()-Y_DELTA <= (s.y + s.width)));
                        System.out.println(e.getX() + " "+ e.getY()+ " " + s.x+ " "+ s.y);
                        if (e.getX() >= s.x && e.getX() <= (s.x + s.width) &&
                                e.getY()-Y_DELTA >= s.y && e.getY()-Y_DELTA <= (s.y + s.width)) {
                            CurrentSticker = s;
                             f=false;
                            JToolBar jtb = window.getStickerToolbar();
                            jtb.setVisible(true);
                            System.out.println("условние работает");
                            window.stickerToolBarActivated = true;
                            setListeners(s, pt, jtb);
                            f = false;


                            //Sticker buf = (Sticker) CurrentSticker.clone();
                            //pt.addSticker(buf);
                            d.repaint();

                        } else {
                            window.getStickerToolbar().setVisible(false);
                            sew = null;
                            window.stickerToolBarActivated = false;
                            if(rd!=null)
                            {
                                window.Read.removeActionListener(rd);
                                rd = null;
                            }
                            if(del!=null)
                            {
                                window.Delete.removeActionListener(del);
                                del = null;
                            }
                            if(edit!=null)
                            {
                                window.Edit.removeActionListener(edit);
                                edit = null;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }

       // window.Delete.re
        System.out.println(e.getX()+" "+ e.getY()+" "+"cliicked");
    }

    private void setListeners(Sticker s, ProgressType pt, JToolBar jtb) {
        del = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int iRes = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(window, "Удалить этот стикер?", "",
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                if (iRes == JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) {
                    pt.stickers.remove(s);
                    jtb.setVisible(false);
                    d.repaint();
                }
            }

        };
        edit = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (sew == null) {
                        createStickerEditorWindow(s);
                    }
            }
        };

         rd = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                StickerReadingWindow srw = new StickerReadingWindow(s);

            }
        };
        window.Delete.addActionListener(del);
        window.Edit.addActionListener(edit);
        window.Read.addActionListener(rd);
    }


    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
            for(ProgressType pt: PTs) {
                for (Sticker s : pt.stickers) {
                    if (e.getX() >= s.x && e.getX() <= (s.x + s.width) &&
                            e.getY()-Y_DELTA >= s.y && e.getY()-Y_DELTA <= (s.y + s.width)) {
                        DistanceToTheEndX = e.getX()-s.x;
                        DistanceToTheEndY = e.getY()-s.y;
                        StickerIsBeingDragged = true;
                        CurrentSticker = s;
                        System.out.println(s.x+" "+s.y+" "+e.getX()+" "+ e.getY()+" "+"pressed");
                    }
                }
            }

    }

    private void createStickerEditorWindow(Sticker s)
    {
        DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        for (ProgressType pt: PTs)
            listModel.addElement(pt.name);

        sew = new StickerEditorWindow(s, listModel);

        sew.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                sew=null;
                d.repaint();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if(StickerIsBeingDragged) {
            if(sd2) {
                System.out.println(CurrentSticker.x + " " + CurrentSticker.y + " " + e.getX() + " " + e.getY() + " " + "released");
                StickerIsBeingDragged = false;
                d.repaint();

                if (CurrentSticker.x < 0)
                    CurrentSticker.x = 0;
                else if (CurrentSticker.x > window.getWidth())
                    CurrentSticker.x = window.getWidth() - 15;

                for (ProgressType pt : PTs) {
                    if (CurrentSticker.x >= pt.x && CurrentSticker.x < pt.x + pt.width && CurrentSticker.x >= 0) {
                        CurrentSticker.x = pt.x;
                        Sticker buf = (Sticker) CurrentSticker.clone();
                        pt.addSticker(buf);
                    }

                    if (pt.stickers.indexOf(CurrentSticker) != -1) {
                        pt.stickers.remove(CurrentSticker);
                    }
                }
sd2=false;
                d.repaint();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class StickerEditorWindow extends JFrame {
    private Sticker sticker;
    private JTextField title;
    private JTextArea text;
    private JList ProgressTypes;

    private JButton Save;
    private JButton DelayTitleChanges;
    private JButton DelayTextChanges;
    private JButton DelayProgressTypeChanges;

   // private ArrayList<String> s_text;
    //private String Progress;
    //public String s_title;

    private DefaultListModel listModel;

    public StickerEditorWindow(Sticker s, DefaultListModel lm) {
        this.sticker = s;
        setSize(600,300);
        setTitle("Редактировать стикер");
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
       // setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);


        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints(
                0, 0,
                1, 1,
                4, 0,
                GridBagConstraints.CENTER,
                GridBagConstraints.BOTH,
                new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5),
                0, 0
        );

        title = new JTextField("Тема");
        text = new JTextArea("Введите текст");
        this.listModel = lm;
        ProgressTypes = new JList(listModel);

        this.add(title, gbc);

        ++gbc.gridy;
        gbc.weighty=4;
        this.add(text, gbc);
        this.add(new JScrollPane(text), gbc);
        gbc.weighty=0;

        ++gbc.gridy;
        this.add(ProgressTypes, gbc);
        ProgressTypes.setFocusable(false);
        this.add(new JScrollPane(ProgressTypes), gbc);
        ProgressTypes.setVisible(true);




        Save = new JButton("Cохранить");
        DelayTitleChanges = new JButton("Отменить изм. темы");
        DelayTextChanges = new JButton("Отменить изм. текста");
        DelayProgressTypeChanges = new JButton("Отменить изм. колонки прогресса");

        gbc.gridx=1;
        gbc.weightx=1;

        gbc.gridy = 3;
        this.add(Save, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 0;
        this.add(DelayTitleChanges, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.weighty=4;
        this.add(DelayTextChanges, gbc);

        gbc.gridy = 2;
        this.add(DelayProgressTypeChanges, gbc);


        if(sticker.text!=null) {
                text.setText(sticker.text);
        }
        if(sticker.title!=null)
            title.setText(sticker.title);

        setListeners();

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setListeners()
    {
        StickerEditorWindow w = this;
        this.Save.addActionListener(new StickerChangeListener(w, this.Save));
        this.DelayProgressTypeChanges.addActionListener(new StickerChangeListener(w, this.DelayProgressTypeChanges));
        this.DelayTitleChanges.addActionListener(new StickerChangeListener(w, this.DelayTitleChanges));
        this.DelayTextChanges.addActionListener(new StickerChangeListener(w, this.DelayTextChanges));

    }

    public void SaveStickerChanges()
    {
        sticker.title=title.getText();
        sticker.text = text.getText();
    }

    public void CancelTitleChanges()
    {
        title.setText(sticker.title);
    }

    public void CancelTextChanges()
    {
        text.setText(sticker.text);
    }

}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicOptionPaneUI;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class StickerChangeListener implements ActionListener {
    private StickerEditorWindow sew;
    private JButton sender;
    public StickerChangeListener(StickerEditorWindow sew, JButton sender) {
        this.sew = sew;
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       if(sender.getText().equals("Cохранить")){
           sew.SaveStickerChanges();
       }
       if(sender.getText().equals("Отменить изм. темы")){
           sew.CancelTitleChanges();
       }
       if(sender.getText().equals("Отменить изм. текста")){
           sew.CancelTextChanges();
       }
       if(sender.getText().equals("Отменить изм. колонки прогресса")){}

    }
}
```

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class StickerReadingWindow extends JFrame{
    private Sticker sticker;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    ReadingCrutch rc;

    public StickerReadingWindow(Sticker s) throws HeadlessException {
        this.sticker = s;

        width=height=500;
        String winHeader = "";
        if(sticker.title!=null)
            winHeader+="Тема: "+sticker.title+ " ";

        setTitle(winHeader);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        add(jp);
        Graphics g =jp.getGraphics();




        setSize(width,height);
        setTitle("Редактировать стикер");
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            URL resource = Sticker.class.getResource("\\transparentSticker.png");
            img = ImageIO.read(Paths.get(resource.toURI()).toFile());
            System.out.println("c");
        } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println("caught");
        }
              if(img!=null)
                  rc = new ReadingCrutch(img, sticker.text, width);
       add(rc);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class ReadingCrutch extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage img;
    private String str;
    private int width;
    public ReadingCrutch(BufferedImage img, String str, int w) {
        this.img = img;
        this.str = str;
        this.width =w;
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 450, 450, null);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        String txt = str;
        String [] s=txt.split(" ");
        String buf= "";
        String NormalizedString="";

        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(g.getFont());
        int hgt= fm.getHeight();
        int strw=0;
        for(int i=0; i<s.length; ++i)
        {
            buf+=s[i]+" ";
            strw=fm.stringWidth(buf);
            if(strw>=width*0.75)
            {
                NormalizedString+=buf;
                NormalizedString+="\n";
                buf="";

            }
        }
        NormalizedString+=buf;
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        String[] forWrite= NormalizedString.split("\n");
        for(int i=0; i<forWrite.length; ++i)
        {
            g.drawString(forWrite[i]+" ", 0, 0 + width / 5 + hgt * 13 / 10 * (i + 1));

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Можете пожалуйста более точно описать проблему. Какие действия нужно совершить чтобы вызвать ошибку, что должно произойти, и что происходит на самом деле.

Comment: Если сначала нажать сначала на первый стикер в колонке, потом попробовать нажать на второй, то при нажатии на первый внизу окна появится JToolBar с кнопками. При нажатии на второй почему-то не появляется, хотя хотелось бы, чтобы появлялось

Answer (score 0):

Думаю дело в том, что вы каждый раз передавали несколько или совершенно рандомный(?) экземпляр стикера, а так же новую переменную которая ссылается на единственный тул бар.

Если это вам не помогло, исправьте описание вашего вопроса, а так же, при таком громоздком коде, лучше использовать гитхаб.

```
  @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        boolean f = true;
        
        if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {

            for (ProgressType pt : PTs) {
                for (Sticker s : pt.stickers) {
                    
             /*
             Ваш вывод в консоль информации
              */

                    if (!s.equals(CurrentSticker)) {
                        continue;
                        // Вызываем тул бар на том объекте, по которому нажали!
                    }
                    
                    if (window.getStickerToolbar().isVisible()) {
                        window.getStickerToolbar().setVisible(false);
                        // Скроем тул бар
                        return;
                    }

                    //CurrentSticker = s;
                    //f=false;           // What is it ??

                    window.getStickerToolbar().setVisible(true);
                    System.out.println("условие работает");

                    window.stickerToolBarActivated = true;
                    setListeners(s, pt, window.getStickerToolbar());

                    //f = false;        // What is it ??
                    return;
                }
            }
            // window.Delete.re
            System.out.println(e.getX() + " " + e.getY() + " " + "cliicked");
        }
    }
```